# Process out of memory using ms_simplify() in R

Tags: r, memory, mapping, r-sf

I am using packages sf and rmapshaper to do some mapping under R, but i am running out of memory because of the size of the data.
While i worked on the French departments (smaller data) it worked well, but now i am working on french cities and while performing the ms_simplify() function i get the following error :

V8 FATAL ERROR IN NEW ARRAY: allocation failed - process out of memory

This is a fatal error that makes abort the R session.

The data i am using is at the following link :
https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/r/a01aff2a-8f36-4a77-a73f-efc212fe2899

the code i performed is the following :

```
library(sf)
library(rmapshaper)
shp.city.sf <- read_sf("communes-20200101-shp/communes-20200101.shp")
shp2 <- ms_simplify(shp.city.sf) #, sys_mem=12)
```

I saw similar questions, that have been answered by increasing the size of the memory, but when i use the "sys_mem" argument of the ms_simplify() function, i get the same error (i tried sys_mem=12)

Comment: Hi! Is there any particular reason why you didn't use `st_simplify` instead of `ms_simplify`? I tried running `st_simplify(shp2, dTolerance = 100)` and it works without any particular problem, but I'm not sure about the differences between `st_simplify` and `ms_simplify`.

Comment: Hello ! I basically learned this method in school, with RGDAL package and not sf, and we learned with ms_simplify. I didnt know about the other one ! i may try, and will tell you if the problem is still there ! thanks !

Comment: Section 5.2.1 of this book https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/geometric-operations.html explains the differences bw `st_simplify()` and `ms_simplify()`. `ms_simplify()` seems to operate on each feature in a collection with respect to it's neighbours, and ensures no holes/overlaps are developed between neighbouring polygons when they are simplified, but `st_simplify()` operates on each feature separately so unexpected results may arise. I assume it is because separate operations that `st_simplify()` can operate on collections of different geometries, but `ms_simplify()` can't.

Comment: I would guess that `ms_simplify()` is more memory-heavy as it must process all features at once, whereas `st_simplify()` may process them somewhat separately?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to set sys = TRUE for sys_mem to work.